# Why do parent class methods used by a child class object cause errors?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm currently taking a class about Java and trying to understand a problem that I've come across. Suppose there was the following code:

```
public class Parent
{
     public Parent()
     {}
}
public class Child extends Parent
{
     private int num;
     public Child
     {
          super();
          num = 1;
     }
     public int getNum()
     {
          return num;
     }
}
```

Then, in a separate class from either `Parent`or `Child`:

```
Parent a = new Child();
System.out.print(a.getNum());
```

which should provide the output of:

```
1
```

From what I've learned, this should run without errors, as the `new Child()` portion of the code should dictate what class the object is an instance of, and the `Parent a` portion should set aside space in memory for a `Parent` object dubbed "a", which a `Child` object would be able to fill, due to it being a subclass of the Parent class. The fact that this space is saved for a Parent object simply dictates then that if a method were to appear in both the `Parent` class and `Child` class with different descriptions, the method description of the `Parent` class would have priority over the `Child` class' description of the method (and the opposite description would have priority if the space set aside for `a` was for a `Child` object (ergo `Child a =` etc.)).

I have also been told, however, that this situation would result in an error. I feel like there's something I'm severely misunderstanding about Inheritance as a whole, though everywhere I look seems to give me different answers and conflicting data (this is most likely due to inexperience with the language, though the information is still not coming across because of this). Would somebody be willing to explain why this code provides the response that it does, and how I should change something within this code to make it provide the expected output and why the new code works? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think [the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) are a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines given below won't be compiled because you haven't defined `getNum()` in `Parent`.

```
Parent a = new Child();
System.out.print(a.getNum()); // Won't be compiled
```

Once you define `getNum()` in `Parent` e.g. as given below

```
public int getNum() {
    return 0;
}
```

the following lines will be compiled successfully and you will get `1` as the output

```
Parent a = new Child();
System.out.print(a.getNum());
```

In this case, the reference, `a` will be able to resolve `getNum()` and then it will check for the instance it is pointing to. Since it is pointing to an instance of `Child`, it will return `1` (from the Child's version of `getNum()`).

If you haven't defined `getNum()` in `Parent` and still want to call `getNum()` using its reference, you need to cast the reference to `Child` as follows and then it will be compiled and executed successfully:

```
Parent a = new Child();
System.out.print(((Child) a).getNum());
```

**Output:**

```
1
```

Comment: So for a subclass to have any methods of its own, there must be the same named method in the superclass for the subclass to override? And on that note, would I not have to do that if I instead declared object `a` as `Child a = new Child();`?

Comment: I have added some more details. I hope, it helps.